# How to create a chess board without gaps between the rows?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a chess board.I am using nested loops to do that. The problem is that there is a gap between two horizontal rows of the block. Below I have create a snippet for 3x3 board.

```js
const board = document.querySelector('#board');
const colors = ["black","gray"]
function start(){
    for(let i = 0;i<3;i++){
        let br = document.createElement('br')
        for(let j = 0;j<3;j++){
            let block = document.createElement('div');
            block.classList.add('block');
            let id = (i * 8) + j
            block.id = id;
            block.style.backgroundColor = colors[(id+i) % 2]
            board.appendChild(block)
        }
        board.appendChild(br)

    }
}
start()
```

```css
.block{
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

I already head about solution using `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block`. How could I remove the gap?

I would also like to see if there is better code for creating chessboard?

Comment: all the answer aren't giving the simple solution which is to use `vertical-align: top;` on the inline-block (baseline alignment is the issue)

Comment: @TemaniAfif This is the same solution a used along ago. I just forgot about that. Thanks for telling telling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gap is there because the `<br>`. `#board { font-size: 0; }` will remove it.

Comment: it's not because of the br tag, it's because of the vertical alignment (remove the br tag and use max-width instead, you will have the same issue

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be trying to create a `table` with `div`s. It's perfectly fine, apart from the fact that you'll need to manage spaces between the blocks with margins, if you ever need them.

You could create a table and use `border-collapse: collapse`

```js
const board = document.querySelector('#board');
const colors = ["black", "gray"]

function start() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr')
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      let block = document.createElement('td');
      block.classList.add('block');
      let id = (i * 8) + j
      block.id = id;
      block.style.backgroundColor = colors[(id + i) % 2]
      tr.appendChild(block)
    }
    board.appendChild(tr)

  }
}
start()
```

```css
.block {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}

#board {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table id="board"></table>
```

Answer (score 3):

try to use flex

```js
function start(n){
    let s='';
    for(let i = 0;i<n;i++){
        s+='<div class="row">'
        for(let j = 0;j<n;j++){
            s+=`<div class="block ${(i+j)%2?'white':''}"></div>`
        }
        s+='</div>'
    }
    board.innerHTML=s;
}

start(3)
```

```css
.block{ height: 70px; width: 70px; background: black }
.white { background: gray }
.row { display: flex }
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="8" oninput="start(this.value)" value=3 /><br>

<div id="board"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for useful tips +1. But the first solution is best for me because I don't know much about flex.

Comment: No problem :) however I think it is good moment/occasion to learn [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using canvas. You can fill the screen with rectangles, each with sidelength `width` ,and starting position (`i*width`,`j*width`). Each rect can be filled with a colour, by specifying the fill colour before drawing. Look into a good HTML Canvas tutorial.